# difference between 2 code segments

Tags: entity-framework

What is the difference between

```
ObjectQuery<SalesOrderHeader> query =
context.Contacts.Include("SalesOrderHeaders").Include("SalesOrderDetails");
```

and

```
Contact contact =
context.Contacts.Include("SalesOrderHeaders.SalesOrderDetails").FirstOrDefault();
```

Any advantage of using one over the other?
My main confusion is for the using 2 `Include` in first one and using 2 tables in second `Include`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your first query is incorrect. When you query `Contacts`, how can you get `SalesOrderHeader` as return type. Also does your `Contact` class has a property for `SalesOrderDetails` apart from `SalesOrderHeaders`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My main concern is the syntax. I'm trying to figure it out. Please assume the tables are related. The table names are just for illustration purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On entity framework you have something called navigation properties (Named on your .edmx model) so you can access related entities based on them, in other words,  you can use your navigation properties to eager load (include) related data..

I'm guessing you have this relationship: One Contact can have many SalesOrderHeaders and one SalesOrderHeader can have many SalesOrderDetails, so if you start loading from contacts entity and want to have both relations loaded you should do:

```
Contact contact = context.Contacts.Include("SalesOrderHeaders").Include("SalesOrderHeaders.SalesOrderDetails").FirstOrDefault();
```

as you can see, we're using first include to bring SalesOrderHeaders from DB and the secound one to bring SalesOrderDetails through SalesOrderHeaders navigation property as we're starting from Contacts

Comment: Thx for answer. Good explanation. Two things 1. In my question, both code will give same results? 2. Is tb1.tb2 syntax used for navigation from one table to another?

Comment: 1. No, 2 includes with 2 different navigation names will bring you more data than 1, so in your example (if your navigation names are well and you have data on tables) you will have more data on first one. On your first code you should have a direct relation between Contacts > SalesOrderHeaders and Contacts > SalesOrderDetails or you'll get an invalid navigation property error.

2. Is used for nav from one "table" THROUGH another. I marked table with quotes because it's not necessarily table name, we're talking about nav property name and it can be different if you change it on your model